# How to access id in modelform validation?

Tags: python, django, forms, validation, model

I have a model and a form created with ModelForm. I am using custom validation and I need access to the id of the record I am currently editing.
Is there a way to transfer a variable to the form by inserting a custom hidden field somehow or any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a hidden field. You can transfer variable from view to form:

**View:**

```
def some_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        some_id = 1

        form = SomeForm(data=request.POST, some_id=some_id)
```

**Form:**

```
class SomeForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'some_id' in kwargs:
            self.some_id = kwargs.pop('some_id')

        super(SomeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```